Image on HTML not loads properly. And it should
I'm doing an html that my teacher tell me to do (She just told me to put random tags with no sense and that's what i do). But i don't know why my image on the bottom of the code is not loading, its on the same folder with the exact same name.
This is the code.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="author" content="Tu Nombre" />
<meta
  name="description"
  content="Página de ejemplo con todas las etiquetas HTML y formulario de matrícula."
/>
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, etiquetas, ejemplo" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
<meta http-equiv="default-style" content="main" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Ejemplo de Todas las Etiquetas HTML y Matrícula</title>
<base href="https://www.ejemplo.com/" target="_blank" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" href="alternate.html" hreflang="es" />
<link rel="author" href="author.html" />
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
<script src="anotherScript.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<style>
  /* Estilo simple para mejorar la visualización */
  body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  label {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
  input[type="text"],
  input[type="date"],
  input[type="file"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  hr {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }



<h1>Título Principal (H1)</h1>
<h2>Título Secundario (H2)</h2>
<h3>Título Terciario (H3)</h3>
<h4>Título Cuaternario (H4)</h4>
<h5>Título Quinto (H5)</h5>
<h6>Título Sexto (H6)</h6>

<p>Este es un párrafo de texto que explica el contenido de la página.</p>
<br />
<hr />

<div>
  <span>Texto en un span.</span>
</div>

<a href="https://www.ejemplo.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  Enlace a Ejemplo
</a>

<h1>Formulario Matriculación</h1>
<form
  action="#"
  method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  accept-charset="UTF-8"
>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Información Personal</legend>
    <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />

    <label for="lname">Apellido:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" required />

    <label for="birthday">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
    <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday" required />

    <label for="nickname">Apodo:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname" maxlength="10" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Curso Anterior</legend>
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="cursoAnterior1"
        name="cursoAnterior1"
        value="DAW"
      />
      Desarrollo De Aplicaciones Web
    </label>
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="cursoAnterior2"
        name="cursoAnterior2"
        value="DAM"
      />
      Desarrollo De Aplicaciones Multiplataforma
    </label>
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="cursoAnterior3"
        name="cursoAnterior3"
        value="IB"
        checked
      />
      Informática Básica
    </label>
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="cursoAnterior4"
        name="cursoAnterior4"
        value="ND"
        disabled
      />
      No tengo estudios
    </label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Imagen</legend>
    <label for="img">Seleccionar imagen:</label>
    <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*" />
    <p>
      <strong>Nota:</strong> Por razones de seguridad no se permitirá que
      envíes archivos.
    </p>
  </fieldset>

  <label for="submitId"></label><br />
  <input type="submit" id="submitId" name="submitId" value="Enviar" /><br />

  <noscript>
    <p>
      JavaScript está deshabilitado en tu navegador. Algunas funciones
      pueden no estar disponibles.
    </p>
  </noscript>

  <label for="Apodo">Apodo:</label>
  <input type="text" id="Apodo" name="Apodo" maxlength="10" /><br /><br />

  <label for="textarea">Comentarios:</label><br />
  <textarea
    id="textarea"
    name="textarea"
    rows="4"
    cols="50"
    readonly
  ></textarea
  ><br />

  <label for="select">Selecciona una opción:</label>
  <select id="select" name="select" multiple size="3">
    <option value="opcion1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="opcion2" selected>Opción 2</option>
    <option value="opcion3">Opción 3</option>
  </select>
  <br />

  <ul>
    <li><abbr title="Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Web">DAW</abbr></li>
    <li>
      <abbr title="Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Multiplataforma">DAM</abbr>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <table>
    <caption>
      Ejemplo de Tabla
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" id="header1">Título 1</th>
        <th scope="col" id="header2">Título 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td headers="header1" rowspan="2">Fila 1</td>
        <td headers="header2">Fila 1, Columna 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td headers="header2" sorted="ascending">Fila 2, Columna 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Pie de tabla</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>

  <object
    data="document.pdf"
    type="application/pdf"
    width="600"
    height="200"
  >
    <param name="src" value="document.pdf" />
    <p>
      Tu navegador no soporta PDF. Descárgalo
      <a href="document.pdf">aquí</a>.
    </p>
  </object>

  <label for="optgroupSelect">Selecciona un grupo:</label>
  <select id="optgroupSelect" name="optgroupSelect">
    <optgroup label="Grupo 1" disabled>
      <option value="opcion1">Opción 1</option>
      <option value="opcion2">Opción 2</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <br />

  <button type="button" name="buttonName" disabled>
    Botón Deshabilitado
  </button>
  <br />

  <input
    type="text"
    id="input1"
    name="input1"
    accept="text/*"
    alt="Texto de entrada"
    checked
    disabled
    maxlength="50"
    readonly
    size="20"
    src="source.txt"
    value="Valor de entrada"
  />
  <br />

  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col span="2" />
    </colgroup>
    <dl>
      <dt>Término 1</dt>
      <dd>Definición 1</dd>
      <dt>Término 2</dt>
      <dd>Definición 2</dd>
    </dl>
    <ol start="1" type="1">
      <li value="1">Elemento 1</li>
      <li>Elemento 2</li>
      <li>Elemento 3</li>
    </ol>
  </table>
</form>

<p>
  <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Imagen de un botón</b>
  <input
    type="image"
    src="boton.png"
    alt="La imagen no puede mostrarse"
    width="200"
    height="52"
  />
  <br />
</p>

<footer>
  <p>&copy; 2024 Hugo. Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
  <a href="#top" title="Volver al inicio">Volver al inicio</a>
</footer>

My only way to make this work is to delete half on the code and it works, so the problem its on the code itself, but I don't see whats failing.

You forgot the closing style tag. Add  on the line after the hr { border: 1px solid #000; }

Putting code through a validator can often help track down things you can't see. Try putting it through e.g. https://validator.w3.org/

Also, using your browser devtools inspect facility should enable you to see why the image wasn't loaded.

Tell your teacher that HTML does not use and does not need closing slashes on self-closing tags such as <meta>

Did you manage to solve your problem? If so, consider adding an answer detailing your solution so others might have access to the resource. If you still need help, let us know what's going on so we can further assist :)
